# PDF Voice Reader

Tags: pdf, accessibility, text-to-speech

I have been reading PDF files a lot lately and I would very much prefer it if someone could read it out aloud for me ;). Is there any software that you use that can read PDF files aloud so that you can hear it, rather than read?

Comment: I realize this question is specific to Mac users.  In case any Windows users come across this question, [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) provides this functionality.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with OS X's built in speech synth and Preview PDF-reading app. Here's how:

1. Open System Preferences → Dictation & Speech → Text to Speech.
2. Check the box (if it isn't already checked) that is labeled "Speak selected text when the key is pressed". Then, click the "Change Key…" button to the right. Press the keyboard shortcut you want to use (I use shift-cmd-r).
3. Now, open you PDF in Preview. Select what you want with the Select tool, or use cmd-a to select everything. Press the key you set earlier, and your computer will think for a moment and then read you your PDF.
   Press your key again to stop.

Comment: In newer versions (I use Sierra) it's now under System Preferences → Accessibility → Speech

Answer (score 1):

An update for MacOS Big Sur (at least)

1. Go to `System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Spoken Content`
2. Make sure `Speak selection` is checked
3. Then highlight some text, right click, and click on `Speech -> Start Speaking`